# Selecting value from SQL sever using exists

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Hai all I am currently doing a project for a hospital clinical lab. I have come across a problem while fetching data from database. The problem is as follows.

I have 2 category of tests namely Single test and Profile test. The master table of tests contain both the category of tests.

**MASTER TABLE of TESTS(LAB_TEST_SERVICES)**

```
CREATE TABLE LAB_TEST_SERVICES (inttestid bigint identity NOT NULL IDENTITY,
testid varchar(15) NOT NULL, testname varchar(255) NOT NULL, cptdesc varchar(300),
splinstr varchar(300), tstabbr varchar(25), reordertime numeric(15),
tstduration numeric(15), autocancel numeric(15), minbiltime numeric(15),
status int NOT NULL, maxbiltime numeric(15), PRIMARY KEY (inttestid));
```

The type and category of test is stored in following table

**LAB_SERVICES_TYPE**

```
CREATE TABLE LAB_SERVICES_TYPE (inttypeid bigint identity NOT NULL IDENTITY,
inttestid bigint NOT NULL, testtype varchar(25), visitype int NOT NULL,
appgendr char(2) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (inttypeid));
```

If the test comes under single test category, I need to fill the details to the columns of following tables namely LAB_SPECIMEN_MAPPING,LAB_PARAMETER_MAPPING and LAB_TEST_LOCATION.

**LAB_SPECIMEN_MAPPING**

```
CREATE TABLE LAB_SPECIMEN_MAPPING (inttestspcid bigint identity NOT NULL IDENTITY,
inttestid bigint NOT NULL, intspcid bigint NOT NULL, intcontid bigint NOT NULL,
volcol numeric(15, 3) NOT NULL, volreq numeric(15, 3) NOT NULL,
status int NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (inttestspcid));
```

**LAB_PARAMETER_MAPPING**

```
CREATE TABLE LAB_PARAMETER_MAPPING (intparaid bigint identity NOT NULL IDENTITY,
inttestid bigint NOT NULL, paraname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
parseq numeric(15, 3) NOT NULL, resulttype varchar(30), shortname varchar(30),
mand int NOT NULL, derived int NOT NULL, status int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (intparaid));
```

**LAB_TEST_LOCATION**

```
CREATE TABLE LAB_TEST_LOCATION (intlocid bigint identity NOT NULL IDENTITY,
intlabid bigint NOT NULL, inttestid bigint NOT NULL, status int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (intlocid));
```

And if the test comes under Profile Test category then I need to fill the details to the columns of following table namely LAB_PROFILE_TEST_LIST. Here for each profile test I am mapping a single test to it.

**LAB_PROFILE_TEST_LIST**

```
CREATE TABLE LAB_PROFILE_TEST_LIST (intproftestid int identity NOT NULL IDENTITY,
intprotestid int NOT NULL, intsintestid int NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (intproftestid));
```

I had done the following code to find the name of test which is mapped ie for single test if it is mapped then the testid(inttestid from LAB_TEST_SERVICES) will be inserted in LAB_SPECIMEN_MAPPING,LAB_PARAMETER_MAPPING and LAB_TEST_LOCATION or if the test is profile test the testid(inttestid from LAB_TEST_SERVICES) will be inserted in LAB_PROFILE_TEST_LIST.

**The tests which is mapped ( both single & profile test).(My contribution to my problem).**

```
SELECT *
FROM LAB_TEST_SERVICES lts
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT lsm.inttestid 
    FROM LAB_SPECIMEN_MAPPING lsm
    WHERE lsm.status = 1
    AND lts.inttestid = lsm.inttestid)
AND EXISTS
(SELECT ltl.inttestid 
    FROM LAB_TEST_LOCATION ltl
    WHERE ltl.status = 1
    AND lts.inttestid = ltl.inttestid) 
AND EXISTS 
(SELECT lptr.intprotestid
    FROM LAB_PROFILE_TEST_LIST lptr WHERE lts.inttestid = lptr.intprotestid)
```

So when I tried to do this no tests appear because I know that there will be no tests having both the characteristics of Single and Profile tests. I had done so many things but cant find a solution. Kindly help me to find out the details tests which is mapped both single and profile.I am using Java, Hibernate and SQL SERVER. Thanks in advance

Comment: in your last sentence you write that _no tests appear because I know that there will be no tests having both the characteristics of Single and Profile tests_ so you already know that you cannot get a result if you look for tests mapped both as single and profile. how do you expect to find a result if you already know that such a result does not exists?

Comment: I am not trying to get a result  for tests mapped both as single and profile.I need to get the details of single test which is mapped and as well as profile test which is mapped in a single query to display in a window. Please refer to my question what mapping means for me.

Comment: did you try to use `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: Yes I do single test list is working correctly but if I use OR then profile test wont work correctly